# How to generate unique random numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, random, unique

I'm having trouble with this assignment that requires me to create 50 random unique numbers without using ArrayLists. I'm required to use a boolean array that checks whether the random number has already been generated. Each number that is generated out of 50 will be set to true in the boolean array. Ex. Generating a number 23 would make check[23]=true. The problem I am having is an error in the while loop that keeps on generating a new random number even if there is no other unique number left. How can I solve this problem while still using a boolean array to check uniqueness.

```
int rnd;
Random rand=new Random();Random rand=new Random();
int[] nums = new int[50];
boolean[] check = new boolean[51];

rnd = rand.nextInt(50) +1;
for (int k = 0; k<50; k++)
{
    //Loop for when there number is already chosen
    while (check[rnd]==true)
    {
        rnd = rand.nextInt(50) +1;
    }
    //Sets the random unique number to a slot in the array
    if(check[rnd]==false)
    {
        nums[k]=rnd;
        check[rnd]=true;
    }
    rnd = rand.nextInt(50) +1;
}
System.out.println(nums);
```

Comment: So the problem you're experiencing is that you're trying to fill a 51-slot array with 50 unique integers?

Comment: Please be more specific about your assignment's requirements. The boolean array makes no sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to generate 50 unique random integers from 1 to 50.  That's really just a complicated way to say you're trying to shuffle the numbers 1-50 into a random order, isn't it?

Comment: yeah but my classes instructor requires us to use Random in our program

Comment: If the boolean array a requirement? Guess-and-check is really a poor way to do a shuffle.

Comment: yes the boolean array is too

Comment: pity, otherwise you could just use [the fisher-yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle)

Comment: Your code seems to work properly. It is generating exactly 50 unique numbers. So where's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class random {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        int[] numbers = new int[50];
        boolean[] check = new boolean[50];
        int amountFilled = 0;
        int trial;
        while (amountFilled < 50) {
            trial = myRandom.nextInt(50);
            if (!check[trial]) {
                check[trial] = true;
                numbers[amountFilled] = trial;
                amountFilled++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Your real problem was the `System.out.println(nums);` statement. It doesn't do what you what it to do. And the double `Random rand=new Random();`. The rest of the code is OK. I rewrote it in a clearer/simpler way, but what you had already works if you fix the output statement.

Answer (score 0):

Few tweaks done:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int rnd;

        Random rand=new Random();
        int[] nums = new int[50];
        boolean[] check = new boolean[50];
        for (int k = 0; k<50; k++)
        {
            rnd = rand.nextInt(50);

            //Loop for when there number is already chosen
            while (check[rnd])
            {
                rnd = rand.nextInt(50);

            }
//Sets the random unique number to a slot in the array
                nums[k]=rnd;
                check[rnd]=true;

        }

        for(int num : nums){
            System.out.println("\n" + num);

        }

    }
}
```